# pyspark: Apply functions on every fields of the RDD

Tags: pyspark

I created dataframe using df1 = HiveContext(sc).sql("from xxx.table1 select * ") Converted to RDD df1.rdd

I have to apply transformations at field level in a row. How do I do it?

I tried the below code:

```
df2 = rdd1.map(lambda row:
        Row(row.fld1,
            row.fld2.replace("'", "''").replace("\\","\\\\").strip(),
            row.fld3.toLowerCase
        )
)
```

I get error

> AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute toLowerCase/replace

Could you help?

Comment: Hi,
I got this working by changing my code as below:
rdd2 = rdd1.map(lambda row: str(row).lower().replace("'", "''").replace("\\", "\\\\").strip() \
                    if (type(row) == str or type(row) == unicode or\
                         (not row.apn or not row.fips_code or not row.dupl_apn)) else row)

Hope it will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
row.fld3.toLowerCase
```

by

```
row.fld3.lower()
```